# [__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: json, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get a value for a particular key from a dictionary but i get a "[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSDictionary *avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"response:::%@", avatars);
if(avatars){
    NSDictionary *avatarimage = [avatars objectForKey:@"- image"];
    NSString *name = [avatars objectForKey:@"name"];
}
}
```

I NSLog my avatars Dictionary and my result is:

```
(
{
    "created_at" = "2013-06-06T11:37:48Z";
    id = 7;
    image =         {
        thumb =             {
            url = "/uploads/avatar/image/7/thumb_304004-1920x1080.jpg";
        };
        url = "/uploads/avatar/image/7/304004-1920x1080.jpg";
    };
    name = Drogba;
    "updated_at" = "2013-06-06T11:37:48Z";
}
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is you have a `NSArray` not an `NSDictionary`. The `NSArray` has a count of 1 and contains an `NSDictionary`.

```
NSArray *wrapper= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *avatars = [wrapper objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

To loop through all items in the array, enumerate the array.

```
NSArray *avatars= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *avatar in avatars) {
    NSDictionary *avatarimage = avatar[@"image"];
    NSString *name = avatar[@"name"];

    // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

NOTE: I also switched from `-objectForKey:` to [] syntax. I like that better.

Comment: yes this works but what if I have more than one object? do i get number of objects from `NSArray` and then loop it? Also how is this an `NSArray` and not a `NSDictionary`

Comment: strange, i thought my plist should have returned an array, but you were right i needed a wrapper array. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see that is because `avatars` is not a `NSDictionary` but is a `NSArray` instead.

I can tell because:

- the exception you get tells that `__NSCFArray` (i.e. `NSArray`) doesn't recognize the `objectForKey:` selector
- when logging `avatars` it prints also parenthesis `(`. An array is logged in this way:

  (
    first element,
    second element,
    …
  )

while a dictionary gets logged in this way:

```
{
  firstKey = value,
  secondKey = value,
  …
}
```

You can fix this in this way:

```
NSArray *avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"response:::%@", avatars);
if(avatars){
    NSDictionary *avatar = [avatars objectAtIndex:0]; // or avatars[0]
    NSDictionary *avatarimage = [avatar objectForKey:@"- image"];
    NSString *name = [avatar objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Also note that the key for the `avatarImage` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks.So this is an array containing NSDictionary?Also in your answer you use the same key as I did `- image`, I suppose it's a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dct =[avatars objectAtIndex:0];

 NSDictionary *avatarimage = [dct objectForKey:@"- image"];

 NSString *name = [dct objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: I was getting an error with this code `no visible interface for a