# UITableView and JSON error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to fill a UITableView with results from JSON via a url. Im getting a cryptic error ( cryptic to me since this is my first iOS app ).

here is my code:

```
#import "VideoListViewController.h"
#import "Videos.h"
#import "JSONLoader.h"


@implementation VideoListViewController{
NSArray *_videos;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Create a new JSONLoader with a local file URL
JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password=1b75e458de33a9b3f99d33f6bf409a7e145c570a&project_id=kx3rkgrv2w"];

// Load the data on a background queue...
// As we are using a local file it's not really necessary, but if we were connecting to an online URL then we'd need it
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    _videos = [jsonLoader locationsFromJSONFile:url];
    // Now that we have the data, reload the table data on the main UI thread
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
});
 }



#pragma mark - Table View Controller Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

Videos *videos = [_videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = videos.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = videos.id;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_video.png"];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [_videos count];
}



@end
```

It never makes it past the dispatch_async call, it just skips over it and then errors out with this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c9d0d0'.

The format of the json returned I noticed does not have a selector for the info I am pulling maybe that is the problem?

Thanks,
Sam

### EDITED

Here is the JSONLoader method:

```
- (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
// Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];

// Get the data
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

// Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

// Create a new array to hold the locations
NSMutableArray *videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@""];
// Iterate through the array of dictionaries
for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    // Create a new Location object for each one and initialise it with information in the dictionary
    Videos *video = [[Videos alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
    // Add the Location object to the array
    [videos addObject:video];
}

// Return the array of Location objects
return videos;
```

}

Comment: It looks like you have exactly the same problem as someone [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963259/nscfarray-objectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON format.  It takes 5 minutes, 10 if you're a slow reader.  Then use NSLog to dump your received JSON before you parse it.  (If necessary use NSString initWithData to convert received NSData to NSString first.)  Is the outermost JSON structure an "object" or an "array"?

Comment: (Or if you want to dump your parsed JSON with NSLog you can do that, only understand that instead of `[]` around a JSON array, an NSArray has `()`.)

Comment: And, BTW, learn how to read an exception traceback or use an exception breakpoint to identify the location of your exception.

Comment: Thanks, I figured my first attempt at iOS would be bumpy coming from C# :)

Comment: (Your failure is probably occurring in `locationsFromJSONFile`.)

Comment: Looks like the outermost JSON structure is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (if not all) Objective-c JSON parsers convert objects to instances of NSDictionary class and arrays to instances of NSArray class.

What happens somewhere in your program is that where it assumes it deals with NSDictionary, it actually has an NSArray. I have no idea how your JSON looks like though, so can't say where it happens. Use breakpoints to find out. The problem could be in that JSONLoader class, so if you made it yourself, it might be good idea to check there. If you still have problems, show us code of locationsFromJSONFile method.

Comment: I edited my post and added JSONLoader. The outermost JSON appears to be an object and that is what I am grabbing two fields from.

Comment: It's failing here:  // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@""];  this is where I removed the objectForKey since the outermost JSON doesn't have a key it's just an object with fields like so "[{"id":2687053,"name":"Video One - Build","type":"Video","created":"2013-01-30T19:29:49+00:00","updated":"2013-03-01T21:04:53+00:00","duration":151.48,"hashed_id":"23v34h4ug4","description":"","progress":1.0,"status":"ready","thumbnail":{"url":"http://embed.wistia.com/deliveriese6e5.jpg?image_crop_resized=100x60","width":100,"height":60}"

Comment: So if the JSON doesn't have an objectForKey what do I set this line to?   NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

Comment: From your JSON, the [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] method will return instance of NSArray, not NSDictionary. It should be NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]

Comment: I tried that and now I get the error:  "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c460b0'"

Comment: Can you trace in which line is it happening?

Comment: Yeah it's where I set the ID field here: cell.detailTextLabel.text = videos.id; Do I need to cast it as a string? I assumed everything came in as a string from JSON.

Comment: No, it can i.e. be instance of NSNumber (which it is in your case).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46522/discussion-between-sam-cromer-and-johnyu)