# iOS: JSON parsing to NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

Hi I am getting the folowing JSON as response but getting error when try to parse it to NSArray.

**NSArray * resp = [JSON objectForKey@"CONVCOLL"];**

It throws exception to the above line. please help

```
(
 {
        ACT1 = "<null>";
        ACT2 = "<null>";
        AUTRECERTI = "<null>";
        AUTRESTI = "<null>";
        CONVCOLL = "CCT romande du second oeuvre";
        DESCPHILO = "<null>";
        DESCSUCC = "<null>";
        DIRECTION = "M. Aldo Zoppi, chef d'entreprise";
        DISPHYGSEC = 1;
        FILIALES = "<null>";
        ISO14000 = 0;
        ISO9000 = 0;            
        ZONEACT = "La Riviera, Lavaux et Lausanne";
    },
        {
        ACT1 = "<null>";
        ACT2 = "<null>";
        AUTRECERTI = "<null>";
        AUTRESTI = "<null>";
        CONVCOLL = "<null>";
        DESCPHILO = "<null>";
        DESCSUCC = "<null>";
        DIRECTION = "<null>";
        DISPHYGSEC = 0;
        FILIALES = "<null>";
        ISO14000 = 2;
        ISO9000 = 1;            
        ZONEACT = "<null>";
    },
        {
        ACT1 = "<null>";
        ACT2 = "Volets en aluminium";
        AUTRECERTI = "<null>";
        AUTRESTI = "<null>";
        CONVCOLL = "<null>";
        DESCPHILO = "<null>";
        DESCSUCC = "<null>";
        DIRECTION = "M. Denis Zurbuchen, directeur et M. Jacques Zurbuchen, directeur d'exploitation";
        DISPHYGSEC = 1;
        FILIALES = "<null>";
        ISO14000 = 0;
        ISO9000 = 0;            
        ZONEACT = "<null>";
    }
)
```

Comment: It looks like your JSON is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject,  loop through the JSONArray of JSONObjects, and on each JSONOBject, make the call above.

Comment: Read (and include) the exception message or other error symptoms.

Comment: -1 for not including the exact exception message.  (But one can guess it was something like "unrecognized selector" -- the outermost "layer" is an array, not a dictionary.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[\_\_NSCFArray objectForKey:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963259/nscfarray-objectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: First of all, the JSON posted in the question is invalid. JSON needs to start with '[' or '{'. The round brace '(' is not a valid JSON markup.

Comment: @iCoder -- His is a dump of the `description` of an NSArray.  The JSON has already been parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your URL response as an instance of `NSData`. So you can parse it and loop through your received array:

```
NSArray *JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

for(NSDictionary *entry in JSONArray) {
    NSLog(@"CONVCOLL: %@", [entry objectForKey:@"CONVCOLL"]);
}
```

Comment: He already has the data parsed.  His dump is an NSArray, not JSON.

Comment: When `JSON` is the parsed data, so you have an array. This means, you have to access it's values correctly. You have to either loop through the entries (like in my code) or you have to access by index: `[JSON objectAtIndex:0];`. Your array contains `NSDictionaries`. This means (like also in my code): `[[JSON objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"CONVCOLL"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
    NSString *response=[request responseString];

    NSArray *responseArray=[response JSONValue];

    for(NSDictionary *dict in responseArray)
    {

    self.convcoll.text=[dict objectForKey:@"CONVCOLL"];

    }
```

if you are using ASIFormDataRequest to parse..

```
NSArray * resp = [JSON objectForKey@"CONVCOLL"];// this way of retrieving is not correct for above JSON..
```

Hope it helps you..