# Reading Element in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsmutablearray

I have created an NSMutableArray based on the JSON Elements in a Twitter Tweet. However when attempting to read an element from the array I get this error:

```
 -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea49d31730
2015-03-09 00:30:53.492 Floadt[3963:325552] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea49d31730'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059c7f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105660bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059cf04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010592727c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105926e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Floadt                              0x00000001022cf456 -[TweetDetailViewController detectEntitesAndOrganize] + 1462
    6   Floadt                              0x00000001022ccb75 -[TweetDetailViewController viewDidLoad] + 853
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001044cda90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001044cdc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001044f1507 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001044fd3fe -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001044fdf47 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104643509 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104421973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001041f4de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001041e9a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001041e987e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010415763e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010415874a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104158db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058fcdc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058fcd20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058f2b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058f2486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010734f9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001043a8420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    26  Floadt                              0x00000001022d30d3 main + 115
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107b74145 start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is my code in how I am attempting to read the NSMutableArray:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = self.detailItem;
NSMutableArray *hashtag = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"hashtags"];
NSLog(@"Number of Hashtags = %ld",hashtag.count);
self.numberOfHashtags = hashtag.count;
if (self.numberOfHashtags>0){
    NSString *hashtag = tweet[@"entities"][@"hashtags"][@"text"];
    NSLog(@"Hashtags: %@",hashtag);
}
NSMutableArray *url = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"];
NSLog(@"Number of URL's = %ld",url.count);
self.numberOfUrls = url.count;
if (self.numberOfUrls>0){
    NSString *url = [[[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"] objectForKey:@"display_url"];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@",url);
}
NSMutableArray *user_mention = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"user_mentions"];
NSLog(@"Number of User Mentions = %ld",user_mention.count);
self.numberOfMentions = user_mention.count;

NSMutableArray *media = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"];
NSLog(@"Number of Media = %ld",media.count);
self.numberOfMedia = media.count;
if (self.numberOfMedia>0){
    NSString *media = [[[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"media"] objectForKey:@"media_url"];
    NSLog(@"Media URL: %@",media);
}
```

Comment: your error simply says that you are sending a message objectforkey to nsarray infact you can only pass this message objectforkey to nsDictionary .

Answer (score 0):

As the error says.

```
[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]
```

You are treating NSArray as NSDictionary. Because `objectForKey:`  applies on NSDictionary.

And also from your code if you realize this

Code No:1

```
NSMutableArray *hashtag = [[tweet objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"hashtags"];
```

This is an array of hashtags and in second line you have

Code No:2

```
 NSString *hashtag = tweet[@"entities"][@"hashtags"][@"text"];
```

If you rethink `tweet[@"entities"][@"hashtags"]` this returns an array  `hashtag` of hashtags same of your above Code No:1. And from array you are trying to fetch object in key `text` which is the exact issue.

You should go to for loop to get each text from `hastags` array

```
for(NSString *strhastag in hashtag){
  NSLog(@"your strhastag = %@",strhastag); // This will return you all hastags
}
```

Comment: So now that it returns a whole object how would I access the individual elements in all the hashtags returned

Comment: I had given you to have for loop to access all hasthags. Code is already there with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Array and contains Array of Dictionary so if you perform operation `objectForKey` on `NSArray` will crash with error message "Unrecognized selector"

check this [[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963259/nscfarray-objectforkey-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance?answertab=active#tab-top)

This might helps you :)